# Stuck in loop within a function (C++)

Tags: c++, function, validation, switch-statement

I have written a program with several menus within it. I am now debugging the program and I wanted to include some input validation in the menu choices. However, for some reason, when it detects a wrong input it goes back to the beginning of the function with a `goto` statement (I know, bad practice :\) and It asks the user for a new input, but even if the input is right, it goes back to the case for non allowed inputs (default) no matter what. Does anyone have any idea of what's going on?

NOTE:

`select_variable_check(vector<int> , int)` is a function that checks if the value entered has been entered before if that is of any relevance, although I don't think it has anything to do with it.

```
    void select(vector<int>&select_control) {
        char select;
    choices:
        cin >> select;
        int selectint = select;
        bool check = select_variable_check(select_control, selectint);
        switch (select) {
        case ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'):



            if (check == false) {

                string city = city_selection(selectint);
                double xcoor = xcoor_selection(selectint);
                double ycoor = ycoor_selection(selectint);

                cout << "\n" << city << "\n";

                select_control.push_back(selectint);

                cout << "\n Enter next city:  ";

                cin >> select;
                selectint = select;


            }

            else {

                cout << "You have already selected that city, please select another one ";

                cin >> select;

            }
            break;



        case '99': {
            cout << "TERMINATING" << endl;
            Sleep(3000);
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
        case '100': {
            cout << "input complete" << endl;
            break;

        }
        default: {
            cout << "not a valid value, please try again" << endl;
            goto choices;
            break;

        }


        }
```

Comment: You must put a "break" at the end of each case, otherwise the program will execute the code in the right case and then continue with the following case.

Comment: Tried that, but still doesn't work :/

Comment: mmm. Putting break in the right places should fix the problem. Replace the source in your message with the new one with the break's.

Comment: `exit` is a dangerous hammer to use. [It terminates the program without proper clean up.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) This typically isn't a problem with a small test program or a school assignment with few dependencies and little going on, but for a larger program that may have acquired and locked resources, objects to destroy, or have tasks to perform when the program is shutting down the abrupt termination of the program will have unsavoury side effects.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10')` is `'10'`, so that's the only value that will trigger that first case statement. The right way to write this is:

```
case '1':
case '2':
case '3':
...
```

Even with this change, though, `'10'` is a peculiar kind of character, and almost certainly not the right thing here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code boils down to

```
start:
    get_input
    process_input
    if good do something
    else go to start
end:
```

Now when you enter bad input it goes back to start.  Your input operation will fail again as the input stream is still in an error state so you do not get new input and since you have bad input you go back to start.  To stop this loop you need to clear out the error flags on the stream and remove any input still in the buffer.  That will make you default case look like

```
default: {
    cout << "not a valid value, please try again" << endl;
    cin.clear();  // removes error flags
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');  // flushes input buffer
    goto choices;
    break;
}
```

You will need to `#include <limits>` to use `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')`

Comment: That gives me an error of an illegal token on right side of ::

Comment: @Npm1468 I added to my answer.  You need to add `#include <limits>` to you code.

Comment: @Npm1468 I had a typo in my code.  It was missing a semicolon.  `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')` should be `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: Oh no sorry I corrected that, but the error is still there

Comment: Can you post the updated code then somewhere so I can look at it?  It seems like it is a typo issue.

Comment: its just what you gave me, the ::max(); its that bracket after max